# Add extra values to the the document in JSON API Response

Tags: 8

I have JSON API with filters. Its working fine.
For example:

```
{baseURL}/jsonapi/node/article?filter[X]=Y&sort=title&fields[node--article]=title,drupal_internal__nid
```

At the end of the Response I want to add some extra values. After digging through the `jsonapi module`, I found a Class file where the Response data is being prepared and sent from.

```
core/modules/jsonapi/src/Normalizer/JsonApiDocumentTopLevelNormalizer.php
```

In the normalize function, I want to add my info something like this:

```
$document['MY_INFO'] = "This is the extra Information";
```

The code for normalize function is:

```
public function normalize($object, $format = NULL, array $context = []) {
  assert($object instanceof JsonApiDocumentTopLevel);
  $data = $object->getData();
  $document['jsonapi'] = CacheableNormalization::permanent([
    'version' => JsonApiSpec::SUPPORTED_SPECIFICATION_VERSION,
    'meta' => [
      'links' => [
        'self' => [
          'href' => JsonApiSpec::SUPPORTED_SPECIFICATION_PERMALINK,
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ]);
  if ($data instanceof ErrorCollection) {
    $document['errors'] = $this->normalizeErrorDocument($object, $format, $context);
  }
  else {
    // Add data.
    // @todo: remove this if-else and just call $this->serializer->normalize($data...) in https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi/issues/3036285.
    if ($data instanceof EntityReferenceFieldItemListInterface) {
      $document['data'] = $this->normalizeEntityReferenceFieldItemList($object, $format, $context);
    }
    else {
      $document['data'] = $this->serializer->normalize($data, $format, $context);
    }
    // Add includes.
    $document['included'] = $this->serializer->normalize($object->getIncludes(), $format, $context)->omitIfEmpty();
    // Add omissions and metadata.
    $normalized_omissions = $this->normalizeOmissionsLinks($object->getOmissions(), $format, $context);
    $meta = !$normalized_omissions instanceof CacheableOmission
      ? array_merge($object->getMeta(), ['omitted' => $normalized_omissions->getNormalization()])
      : $object->getMeta();
    $document['meta'] = (new CacheableNormalization($normalized_omissions, $meta))->omitIfEmpty();
  }
  // Add document links.
  $document['links'] = $this->serializer->normalize($object->getLinks(), $format, $context)->omitIfEmpty();
  // Every JSON:API document contains absolute URLs.
  return CacheableNormalization::aggregate($document)->withCacheableDependency((new CacheableMetadata())->addCacheContexts(['url.site']));
}
```

What will be the right way to achieve this ? Of course we don't want to modify the same class file. Which class/file should be created to alter this and what will be the right way to add a value like this ?

```
$document['MY_INFO'] = "This is the extra Information";
```

**Update:
I found a way to add my extra values to it using:**

```
$document['MY_INFO'] = CacheableNormalization::permanent(["XX"=> 'MY INFORMATION']);
```

Now my question is how do I implement it in my custom module? I don't want to edit the core files.

Comment: You probably don't want to do this at the json:api level, it would be better to do it at the node entity level so that your extra information is available regardless of how the node is viewed.